# Unable to connect the AXIS2 webservice with mysql DB. getting the following issue

Tags: mysql, web-services, soapui

I'm getting this when i trigger a soap request from soapui tool.

```
Using JAVA_HOME    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0
Using AXIS2_HOME   C:\Shrikanth\WebServices_Training\axis2-1.6.2\bin\..
[INFO] [SimpleAxisServer] Starting
[INFO] [SimpleAxisServer] Using the Axis2 RepositoryC:\Shrikanth\WebServices_Tra
ining\axis2-1.6.2\bin\..\repository
[SimpleAxisServer] Using the Axis2 RepositoryC:\Shrikanth\WebServices_Training\a
xis2-1.6.2\bin\..\repository
[SimpleAxisServer] Using the Axis2 Configuration FileC:\Shrikanth\WebServices_Tr
aining\axis2-1.6.2\bin\..\conf\axis2.xml
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[INFO] Deploying module: addressing-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Shrikanth/WebServices_Train
ing/axis2-1.6.2/bin/../repository/modules/addressing-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Shrikanth/WebServices
_Training/axis2-1.6.2/bin/../repository/modules/mex-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Shrikanth/WebServices_Train
ing/axis2-1.6.2/bin/../repository/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: ping-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Shrikanth/WebServices_Training/ax
is2-1.6.2/bin/../repository/modules/ping-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: script-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Shrikanth/WebServices_Training/
axis2-1.6.2/bin/../repository/modules/scripting-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Shrikanth/WebServices_Trai
ning/axis2-1.6.2/bin/../repository/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying Web service: EmployeePortal.aar - file:/C:/Shrikanth/WebService
s_Training/axis2-1.6.2/bin/../repository/services/EmployeePortal.aar
[INFO] Deploying Web service: version.aar - file:/C:/Shrikanth/WebServices_Train
ing/axis2-1.6.2/bin/../repository/services/version.aar
[INFO] Listening on port 8082
[INFO] [SimpleAxisServer] Started
[SimpleAxisServer] Started
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader@1440df3
3306
com.sample.reservation.exception.StorageException: Can not get the data base con
neciton
        at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.getConnection(Storage.java:21
2)
        at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.getEmployeeDetails(Storage.ja
va:89)
        at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.addEmployee(Storage.java:34)
        at com.sample.reservation.EmployeeManagementService.addEmployee(Employee
ManagementService.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.jav
a:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic
(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusines
sLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMe
ssageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostReq
uest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPWorker.service(HTTPWorker.java:30
7)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.doService(Axis
HttpService.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.handleRequest(
AxisHttpService.java:187)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.HttpServiceProcessor.run(HttpS
erviceProcessor.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown initial character set index '255' rece
ived from server. Initial client character set can be forced via the 'characterE
ncoding' property.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1056)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionI
mpl.java:1681)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImp
l.java:3422)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2046)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java
:283)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.getConnection(Storage.java:20
6)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: Can you update you question with the code for your web service implementation?

Comment: Have a look at this [re introduced unknown initial character set index error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991101/re-introduced-unknown-initial-character-set-index-error)