# Unknown initial character set index '255' received from server

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

During attempt to create HibernateSession application fails with exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown initial character set index
>   '255' received from server. Initial client character set can be forced
>   via the 'characterEncoding' property.     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)

I found one possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991101/re-introduced-unknown-initial-character-set-index-error) but unfortunately I do not have access to DB server thus I cannot change its configuration. 
*So please pay attention that this is not a duplicate, because suggested solution was provided for the DB server changes and in my case I don't have such access.*

Is it any chance to fix this issue on client side? Below you can find my pom.xml file and java code where I create session.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Some further investigation showed that the issue was exactly in changes which were done in MySQL v.8.0:

> Character Set Support
>
> Important Change: The default character set has
>   changed from latin1 to utf8mb4. These system variables are affected:
>
> The default value of the character_set_server and
>   character_set_database system variables has changed from **latin1** to
>   **utf8mb4**.
>
> The default value of the collation_server and
>   collation_database system variables has changed from **latin1_swedish_ci**
>   to **utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci**.

All these change were already processed in new version of mysql-connector-java and there is no need to configure your MySQL. So change from `5.1.6` to `5.1.44` fix the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.44</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. I only encountered this issue though when working with MySql on Windows 10 instead of Linux. The steps on how to setup MySql with IntelliJ on Ubuntu is different than on Windows 10.So I prolly missed some steps when initializing MySql in Windows 10.

Comment: As of 2021, going ahead with the latest mysql driver is the best solution.

Answer (score 39):

User below URL, It works for me.

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hybrisdb?characterEncoding=latin1&useConfigs=maxPerformance
```

Comment: Getting: java.sql.SQLException: Can't find configuration template named 'maxPerformance'

Comment: Just adding ?characterEncoding=latin1 did the job

Answer (score 12):

This works for me and you can try this too :)

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=utf8"
```

Answer (score 7):

This Works for me!

```
 <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL"  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdemo?characterEncoding=utf8"></property>
```

Answer (score 2):

This below change worked to me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.44</version>
    </dependency>
```

for this connection

```
    @Bean
@Profile("dev")
public DataSource dataSourceDev() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<yourdatabasehere>");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was using 5.1.6, changed it to 5.1.44. Crazy stuff

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same issue.. So I updated the connector version(8.0.18) and it was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me was appending this to my URL:

```
useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

This completely fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

use below url:-

````
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?characterEncoding=latin1&useConfigs=maxPerformance","root","password" ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, MySql was upgrade to 8.0.34 from version 5 but problem was my java code base is 1.6, struggled alot to find right version which would work with both and found below solution worked for me

MySql Connector = mysql-connector-java-5.1.16

Connection = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb?characterEncoding=latin1&useSSL=false

Comment: I would give you a thousands like if I could, you just saved me hours of pain on RDS with same upgrade from 5 to 8. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem for mysql version 8.0.11 while connection with Java 8 client program. As a solution, I downloaded the latest connector from mysql official site.Below I have mentioned the link:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Choose Platform independent as operating system and download the zip archive.Add the available jar in your build path(add as an external jar).

Hope this would solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You need this connector : Connector\J 5.1 driver.

This is the compatible connector

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score 0):

type this property in your hibernate.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
```

and update your mysql connector to

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem change driver class name as given below 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
this is working fine for me in mysql server 8.0.16 and mysql connector 8.0.16

```
`spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Initial client character set should be forced via the 'characterEncoding' property.
so this worked for me:

```java
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookmanagersystem?characterEncoding=latin1&useConfigs=maxPerformance
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error , following edit in the hibernate.cfg.xml file resolved  the issue for me :

```xml
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?characterEncoding=utf8</property>
```