# Unknown initial character set index '255' received from server, but i don't using pom.xml

Tags: java, mysql

I already looked at this topic: [Unknown initial character set index '255' received from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855622/unknown-initial-character-set-index-255-received-from-server)

but i don't have pom.xml, i am using .jar as dependency.
I've already setted most recently and/or current MySQL connector in my project, but the exception persists.

I am using MySQL 8.0

this started to occur after I updated the MySQL 5 to 8

This is my Connection Class:

```
package br.com.sat.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionFactory {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_wim",
                    "root", "*******");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn, PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
        close(conn, ps, rs);
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn, PreparedStatement ps) throws Exception {
        close(conn, ps, null);
    }

    private static void close(Connection conn, PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if (ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and the Error:

```
java.lang.Exception: erro: 
Unknown initial character set index '255' received from server. Initial client character set can be forced via the 'characterEncoding' property.
    at br.com.poc.dao.RealtimeDAO.<init>(RealtimeDAO.java:31)
    at br.com.poc.controller.RealtimeMB.verNovoInsert(RealtimeMB.java:286)
    at br.com.poc.controller.RealtimeMB.<init>(RealtimeMB.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:37)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getBoolean(TagAttributeImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.isTestTrue(ChooseWhenHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:104)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:995)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This error in RealtimeDAO occur in constructor:

```
private Connection conn;
protected ConnectionFactory connection = new ConnectionFactory();
public RealtimeDAO() throws Exception {

        try {
            this.conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("erro: \n" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of listing what you don't have in reference to another question maybe you should tell us what you have like some code and the full error message

Comment: Thanks Joakim, i've edited this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to the change of default character encoding in MySQL 8.0, so using an older connector that doesn't understand the new enconding will fail. If you have updated to the latest MySQL Connector/J (version 8.0) you also have to make a couple of changes. One of them is that the classname has been changed to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, as otherwise you might still use the older driver.

See also the MySQL upgade documentation for Connector/J:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-upgrading-to-8.0.html

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the answer!

I wanted to give up on your answer, but I do not have the privilege for this.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution for the problem:

changed in Connection class:

```
return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_wim",
                    "root", "*******");
```

to:

```
return DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_wim?characterEncoding=latin1&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "*******");
```

The important here is the:

```
characterEncoding=latin1
```

Comment: This option worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For the resolution of this issue you could change the settings of database in mysql workbench in Options File in Administration section.

For character-set-server change the value to latin1 and collation-server to latin1_swedish_ci.

[image]